# How to retrieve original S3 data from AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto

I have an S3 bucket archiving JSON objects via Kinesis Firehose. Each bucket object can contain multiple JSON objects that can vary in the schema.

**Bucket structure**

```
bucket
└── archive
    └── 2021
        └── 04
            ├── 11
            |   ├── 10
            |   |   └── object-1
            └── 14
                └── 09
                    └── object-2
```

**First object - s3://bucket/archive/2021/04/11/10/object-1**

```
{"id":1,"timestamp":"2021-04-11T10:01:20Z","nestedData":{"moreNesting":{"someData":"value"}}}
{"id":2,"timestamp":"2021-04-11T12:00:31Z","someDifferentlyNestedData":{"differentNesting":{"someOtherData":"value"}}}
```

**Second object - s3://bucket/archive/2021/04/14/09/object-2**

```
{"id":3,"timestamp":"2021-04-14T09:02:30Z","noNestedData":"value"}
```

I have set up a Glue Crawler to create the Data Catalogue Table out of my data.

**Data Catalogue Table**

[image: Data Catalogue Table]

I am using AWS Athena to query that data. When querying, I can retrieve all the columns of the target JSON object with the following query:

**All columns query**

```
SELECT *
FROM archive
WHERE nesteddata.morenesting.somedata = 'value';
```

**All columns query result**

[image: Query results]

I can also retrieve the S3 object path of the JSON object with the following query:

**S3 path query**

```
SELECT "$path"
FROM archive
WHERE nesteddata.morenesting.somedata = 'value';
```

**S3 path query results**

[image: Query results]

**Question**

My question is, how can I retrieve the original JSON object via a query, i.e. how can I have a query result that returns something like the following:

[image: Expected query results]

Comment: @HarshadVyawahare unfortunately I haven't. I had an idea of base64 encoding the JSON and storing it in the JSON as a separate property, but that felt more like a hack than anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having this representation on another table, you could simply create a table with a single `string` field via the Athena console using the `Create table` link.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example create table statement?